# Mandatory validation message, the field property is set to not mandatory

Tags: axapta, erp

I have checked the Maproperties of the field & the data source of the form where this is used and the property is set to 'No'.

Though every time i am filling out the form get the following error:
[image: Field 'Activity number' must be filled in.]

What is the source of the validation error?

Answer (score 2):

If the field is not set to mandatory on the AOT table or the form DataSource, check the `validateWrite()` and `validateField()` on the table and the DataSource.

Fields can also be made mandatory at run-time in code with this style:

`salesTable_ds.object(fieldNum(SalesTable, SalesId)).mandatory(true);`

So you'll have to debug!

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `Info.add` method to pin-point the error.